# Replacement for __wgetmainargs in VS2015

Tags: winapi, visual-c++-2015

Right now I'm using [`__wgetmainargs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff770599.aspx) in order retrieve the array of strings that represent the variables set in the user's environment.

Using VS2013 everything works, however, using VS2015 I get `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __wgetmainargs` errors.

I found that this was [removed](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2015-July/msg04821.html) and that [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a replacement, but I don't need the command line arguments, I need the environment array (for some reason I cannot use `_wenviron`, I just get garbage there).

Which library do I have to add to the linker or which alternative API can I use?

Comment: It's documented as being available in VS2015, I don't see any mention of it being removed.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yeah, but it doesn't work any more and when you google it you get several non-official pages stating that it's removed.

Comment: An option would be to use GetEnvironmentStrings and manually split it up, but that's only my fallback option

Comment: If you want to get the current process' environment, call [GetEnvironmentStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683187.aspx). I don't know, why you would call the most straight forward solution to get the environment *"your fallback"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way for solving this is to use [`GetEnvironmentStrings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683187.aspx) which returns a pointer to a wchar_t sequence of all environment variables which are separated by `\0` and end with `\0\0` which can then be used directly or [separated manually for a transformation into the format needed (GPLv2)](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tgit/commit/d1543192b1de47638e91f9e85931bff7bfe0c18b).